# How to create background image for site

Tags: background-image, html, resolution

I have just made background image for my web-site. But I'm confused - if user have resolution no similar mine, then he will see wrong image right? How can I fix this problem and what resolution is normal for browser?

Answer (score 0):

They will see the correct image, but it will repeat itself.

You have two options:

Create an image, which looks nice when it's repeated. Then you just have to exchange the image.

otherwise you have to disable image repeating, so that the image is just displayed once.

see: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp

It usually looks nice if you define an appropriate background-color after the image ends.

Otherwise there are more advanced ways for full scale background images: http://css-tricks.com/3458-perfect-full-page-background-image/

The "normal" Screen resolution on webpages range from the Smartphone screen (320x480) to 30" screens (2.560 x 1.600). Those are the both (not so uncommon!) extremes. The average is between 1024x768 and 1920x1200.